# Problemas em java para chamar um array

Tags: java

Olá, alguém poderia me falar por que o programa não está achando o array `I` (irei sinalizar no código abaixo :

Erro:

> error: cannot find symbol R+= I[P0]; ^ symbol: variable I location: class matematica 1 error

```
class Matematica {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

    int T = ler.nextInt();

    for(int SN=0 ; SN < T ; SN++){
        int N = ler.nextInt();
        int I[]=new int [N];            
        I[SN]=ler.nextInt();
    }              

    int Q = ler.nextInt();

    for(int SQ=0 ; SQ < Q ; SQ++) {
        int P [] = new int[2];
        P[0] = ler.nextInt();
        P[1] = ler.nextInt();

        while(P[0] <= P[1]) {

            int P0=P[0];
            int R = 0;
            R+= I[P0]; // O erro está nessa linha
            if(P[0] == P[1])          
                System.out.printf("%d",R);

            P[0]++; 
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Como `não está achando`? Tem algum erro ocorrendo?

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
                R+= I[P0];
                    ^
  symbol:   variable I
  location: class matematica
1 error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é porque nessa linha você está criando a variável `I` dentro do bloco `for`, assim:

```
for(int SN=0 ; SN < T ; SN++){
    int N = ler.nextInt();
    int I[]=new int [N];            
    I[SN]=ler.nextInt();
}
```

Dessa forma, a variável `I` só vai existir dentro deste bloco de código.

Uma forma de resolver seria declarar a variável acima do `for`

```
int I[] = new int[0];        
...
for(int SN=0;SN<T;SN++){
    ...
    I = new int [N];
```

---

#### Conselho

Sempre use nomes descritivos para suas variáveis, isso faz com que o código fique **extremamente** mais simples de entender. Se vai declarar uma variável para representar o nome de um cliente, use `String nomeCliente = "Joaquim";`. Dessa forma você (e qualquer pessoa) vai entender o que essa variável faz (praticamente) só de olhar pro nome dela.

Comment: E variáveis, que não sejam constantes, em minúsculo seguindo o padrão CamelCase também.